# .htaccess URL Protection, Only ask for Password

Tags: php, .htaccess, passwords

I have put up the following code in my site and I am getting it correctly. It does ask for Username and Password. However, what I want is to ask only for password. Either the USername should be prefilled or it should not be asked, So that the user only enters the required password and gets access to it.

```
# Do the regex check against the URI here, if match, set the "require_auth" var
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/en/file require_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /home/.htpasswd
AuthName "Protected Area."
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

I dont know if this is possible or not. Please throw some light on this.

Comment: There isn't any possible answer in that..

Comment: An answer clearly states "HTTP auth will always ask for a username and password, and not just a password".

Comment: Why would anyone give a negative to this... I got the answer. This is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. HTTP authentication, at the protocol level, always involves a username and password. However, it's possible to abuse the authentication realm to tell the user what to do, e.g:

```
AuthName "The user name is 'user'"
```

[image: How Google Chrome displays this on Mac OS X]

If this isn't suitable, you will need to use something other than HTTP authentication.